# Exceptions from MainWindowViewModel c'tor appearing to be 'masked' by setting MainWindow DataContext (it's ViewModel) in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In a WPF project its `MainWindow` has its `DataContext` set in XAML like so:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Now, in the constructor of the `MainWindowViewModel` there is some code that runs. On rare occasions this code can generate an `Exception` (let's call it the original Exception) when, for example, there are connectivity issues say.

When such an `Exception` occurs this exception seems to get replaced by another exception telling me that there was a problem in the constructor of the `MainWindowViewModel` and this is the exception that is received in my global error handler in the at the `App.xaml.cs` level.

What I need is for the original `Exception` to be the one that is received by my global error handler.

I don't know, but I have a feeling that the original exception is being masked / replaced because the `MainWindowViewModel` is declared in XAML and not in code?

So, does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can get the exception generated in the c'tor of `MainWindowViewModel` to be received by my global error handler.

For completeness, my global error handler is implemented like in `App.xaml.cs` :

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;
    }

    private void Current_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {

        // Show Dialog with error message.
    }
```

Comment: Its likely supplied as an inner exception, you shouldn't be ignoring those anyway, and your logging framework should be capable of showing the full exception tree. That's assuming you arnt trying to control the flow of your program via global exceptions

Comment: @TheGeneral, I hear what you are saying, but I feel the masking problem is a symptom of how the `DataContext` is being set, so I want to fix this to promote the REAL exception to where I want it to be.

Comment: So have you checked the inner exception ? if its there its not being masked or replaced. The other issues here  are, you dont really have control over what the framework throws. Your options is to catch it your self an handle it. The second is to not put any heavy code in the constructor, or lastly, hookup the DataContext manually.

Comment: Alternatively, create the view model instance in code behind and surround the construction by a try/catch.

Comment: @TheGeneral , again I hear you but I feel it is being masked if  the real exception is being demoted to an inner exception. Sadly, I have no choice about the 'heavy' code in the c'tor.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway i think you know your way forward, just one last note though, inner exceptions aren't a demotion, they are thrown as a concern of the context they are in with an optional inner exception to make known what caused its concern (its exceptional state).

Comment: @TheGeneral, thanks for your help. Your right, in what you say. I should change my way of thinking. Great SO name BTW!

Answer (score 1):

If you set your data context in XAML, the corresponding view model is instantiated while parsing the view. If your view model constructor throws an exception, say `ConnectionException`, XAML parsing will fail, too and wrap this exception in a [`XamlParseException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlparseexception?view=netcore-3.1).

Consequently, in your unhandled exception handler, `e.Exception` will contain a `XamlParseException` and its `InnerException` property will contain your `ConnectionException`.

You can mitigate this problem in different ways.

- Traverse or filter the whole exception tree to handle and handle the target exception(s)
- Create the view model in advance and instantiate the view depending on the result
- Move connection setup to a method or a service and call it after view model construction
- Set the data context explicitly after XAML parsing

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments and suggestions. Very useful.